# Designing two column Android application - switching views?

Tags: java, android, menu, navigation, android-activity

I am building a two column application for Android and I'm wondering how to do the navigation. The left column is the navigation bar. The right one is the content view. Both of them are LinearLayouts.

I have a different activity for all the options. How do I implement my menu into these? It is the same for all the activities (except the current one is highlighted), so copying the same code multiple times seems waste and makes it harder to change it later because I would have to change all the files.

I also have to change the title for every activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical answer would be `Fragments`. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)'s a great tutorial on that topic.

However, depending on the triviality of your requirements, you could also consider using a horizontal `LinearLayout` containing your two original `LinearLayout`s.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should use fragments for your columns.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

**you Should use Fragment control for this. you can call content Fragments on right side (Content View) area with the click on leftSide(Content item/Index) .**

I feel you should follow this link.

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Am not sure but hopes u asked for the same.

Thanks..